# Lie Groups and Lie algebras related to Jordan algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras, exceptional-groups, jordan-algebras

Let $J$ be a Jordan algebra. I knew three relative Lie groups/Lie algebras to $J$.

---

In the paper "*The Capelli Identity, Tube Domains, and the Generalized Laplace Transform*"

> Jacobson [J] has associated two Lie algebras to $J$. For any $x \in J$, let $L(x)$ denote the operator of left multiplication by $x$. Let
> $\mathfrak{p} = \{L(x): x\in J\}$ and let $\mathfrak{t} = [\mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{p}]$. Then $\mathfrak{t}$ is the Lie algebra of the “automorphism
> group” of $J$. Let $$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{t}+\mathfrak{p}$$
> Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is a reductive Lie algebra and above is the Cartan decomposition
> of $\mathfrak{g}$.

The paper [J] mentioned is "*Some groups of Transformations defined by Jordan Algebras I.* "

---

In the note "*Lecture notes in mathematics: an elementary approach to bounded symmetric domains*".

1. The *binary Lie algebras* and *symmetric Lie algebras* were defined on Page 9 and Page 35.
2. The *Meyberg theorem* on the relation to Jordan algebra was proved on Page 19.
3. The construction of Lie algebras can be found in Page 80 and Page 46.

As far as I see, the resulting Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{T}\oplus J\oplus J$ has two copies of $J$.

---

In the book "*Jordan algebras and algebraic groups*".

1. The $J$-structure was introduced in section 1 (it is equivalent to a Jordan algebra structure for characteristics $\neq 2$, section 6). There is a structure group $G$ associated to it.
2. In section 11, we pick some idempotent $a$ to define $S_a$ and give the classification of simple $J$.-structure.  It seems to be related to the exceptional group $E_6$ on Page 115.

---

My question is,

> what is the relation between them? Do we have a list of computation of $\mathfrak{g}$ for real simple $J$'s? Besides, what is the geometry of it? For example, is it the isotopic group of the symmetric domain?